# Get size of inline iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe inline src like:

```
let src = `data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,<html>
    <body>
      <p>Content</p>
    </body>
  </html>`
```

When page loaded I'm creating and adding iframe to the page body:

```
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(iframe)
```

Then I'm setting src to the iframe:

```
iframe.setAttribute('src', src)
```

How can I take width and height of rendered in iframe content and set to iframe width and height and what is the best way to do this (with JS or maybe with CSS)

Comment: what is the purpose of using an iframe rather than a div? cross-origin browser policies make this kind of thing a headache

Comment: You can get the innerHeight & innerWidth of iframe variable.

Comment: @dano, this is because in that iframe actually should be email html which should not be dependent of other styles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, so i'll just answer the part of the question about getting element's proportions and changing them accordingly based on another element.

The easiest way to achieve this is probably using jQuery

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('#changed').css({'height': $('#whatfrom').height(), 'width': $('#whatfrom').width()});  

});
```

```css
#changed {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   outline: 1px solid red;
}

#whatfrom {
   margin-top: 10px;
   height: 150px;
   width: 100px;
   outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="changed">I'll take width and height of the div below me</div>
<div id="whatfrom">Watch.. the element above will take my width and height. What a copycat!</div>
```

obviously change the `#changed` and `#whatfrom` divs to whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use `about:blank` as `src` so you can easily access inside iframe from page without running into *"same origin policy"* issues

```
let html = `<p>Content</p>`;

let iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
document.body.appendChild(iframe);    

iframe.src = 'about:blank';

iframe.onload = function(){
  let win = this.contentWindow; 
  win.document.write(html);  
  console.log('inner width of iframe window=', win.innerWidth);  
}
```

<kbd>**[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Le46ued8/)**</kbd>